# Show thumbnail for url attachment on UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

When you a share a url with the UIActivityViewController, it just shows the Safari compass. I get that this is supposed to show the user that they are sharing a link, but is it possible to get this to show a thumbnail/image instead? I realize it does this if I try and share an image, but I wanted to just share a link here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sharing an `NSURL` directly, you can share an object that implements the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. This can just be an object that wraps the `NSURL` and returns it when the `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` method is called.

You can then implement the optional method `activityViewController:thumbnailImageForActivityType:suggestedSize:` to provide a thumbnail for the share dialog.

**For example:**

```
@interface URLWrapper:UIActivityItemProvider

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

@end

@implementation URLWrapper

+ (instancetype)activityItemSourceUrlWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    URLWrapper *wrapper = [[self alloc] initWithPlaceholderItem:@""];
    wrapper.url = url;

    return wrapper;
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return [self activityViewController:activityViewController itemForActivityType:nil];
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    return self.url;
}

- (UIImage *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController thumbnailImageForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType suggestedSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIImage* thumbnail; // get image from somewhere!
    return thumbnail;
}

@end
```

You can then share wrapped URLs just as you would share normal instances of `NSURL`.

Comment: This does not seem to work (tested with XCode7/iOS9). thumbnailImageForActivityType is never called. Tried with Facebook and mail share options. Perhaps it works with some other share option.

Comment: I think thumbnailImageForActivityType is used for sharing images like in Photos you can select images